# Hubspot form - request is not valid Angular 9

Tags: angular, forms, hubspot

I was trying to use my custom form and send information to Hubspot forms api. But I was getting error: `The request is not valid`. I'am using httpclient from angular libs.

```
 contact() {
    return this.httpClient
        .post('https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/submit/portalid/guiid', {
            body: {
                legalConsentOptions: '',
                fields: [
                    { name: 'email', value: 'example@email.com' },
                    { name: 'firstname', value: 'asd' },
                    { name: 'lastname', value: 'asd' },
                    { name: 'message', value: 'asd' },
                ],
            },
        })
        .subscribe(
            res => {
                console.log(res);
            },
            error => {
                console.log('err', error);
            },
        );
}
```

Email, portalid, guiid I have changed for now, because it is secret.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed body tag from request and it's working now.